# Power heuristic in multiple importance sampling

Tags: importance-sampling

Both [Mitsuba](https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/mitsuba) and [Tungsten](https://github.com/tunabrain/tungsten) use the **power heuristic** to do multiple importance sampling (MIS).

Mitsuba:

```
inline Float miWeight(Float pdfA, Float pdfB) const {
    pdfA *= pdfA;
    pdfB *= pdfB;
    return pdfA / (pdfA + pdfB);
}
```

Tungsten:

```
static inline float powerHeuristic(float pdf0, float pdf1)
{
    return (pdf0*pdf0)/(pdf0*pdf0 + pdf1*pdf1);
}
```

*Advanced Global Illumination* gives the **balance heuristic**:
$$F=\cfrac1N\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\cfrac{f(X_{i,j})}{{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n}\frac{c_k}Np_k(X_{i,j})}$$

The **power heuristic** may be like this:
$$F=\cfrac1N\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\cfrac{f(X_{i,j})p_i(X_{i,j})}{{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n}\frac{n_k}Np_k^2(X_{i,j})}$$

I know they are all valid estimators.

What's the motivation to use the **power heuristic**?

What about the **cube heuristic**?
$$F=\cfrac1N\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^{n_i}\cfrac{f(X_{i,j})p_i^2(X_{i,j})}{{\sum\limits_{k=1}^n}\frac{n_k}Np_k^3(X_{i,j})}$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*PBRT v3* Page 799:

[image]

Veach determined it empirically.